# JUnit not found in new Play Framework app

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

I just started to create my very first Play Framework application following the video in the [project page](https://www.playframework.com/).

I did:

```
brew install typesafe-activator
activator new
```

and this created my app. Running

```
activator run
```

started the server and I was able to hit my localhost URL with success.

Then the guy in the video shows the test classes. We are both using IntelliJ. In his project, there's no error, but in my project, JUnit is somehow not found, I have an error in imports like `import org.junit.*;`.

Running

```
activator test
```

though, run the tests successfully.

Since is my very first experience with this technologies, I don't know whether this is a problem with Play Framework, sbt, JUnit, IntelliJ or what could I do to solve this.

Comment: If the error is in the IDE but the test runs sucessfully in the console, then it most probably is the IDE. Try running "Invalidate Caches/Restart..." option in the find menu of your IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having some help and fixed the problem.

The solution was to point the mouse to the error and wait for some bulb icon to appear (I had to be perseverant until it appeared, actually) and click "Add to XYZ classpath". I remember trying to do this and this option not appearing, rather the IDE suggesting me to create the annotation (e.g., `@Test`).